# Search and Replace using Perl

Tags: perl

I have some tags with values like below,

```
<section>
<title id="ABC0123">is The human nervous system?</title>
<para>A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other, similar questions</para>
<section>
<title id="DEF0123">Terms for anatomical directions in the nervous system</title>
<para>A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other, similar questions</para>
</section>
<section>
<title id="ABC4356">Anatomical terms: is referring to directions</title>
.
.
.
```

The output I need is like below,

```
<section>
<title id="ABC0123">Is the Human Nervous System?</title>
<para>A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other, similar questions</para>
</section>
<section>
<title id="DEF0123">Terms for Anatomical Directions in the Nervous System</title>
<para>A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other, similar questions</para>
<section>
<title id="ABC4356">Anatomical Terms: Is Referring to Directions</title>
.
.
```

how could I do this using perl. Here all prepositions and articles will be in lower case. Now the condition is slightly differs as below

condition is if a word that is in @lowercase (suppose is) and it is the first word of the  and is in lower case then it should be upper case. Again if any @lowercase word after colon in the  should be in upper case.

Comment: can you tell me these tags in file or in script?

Comment: So you want to apply an "arbitrary" upper/lower case modification to all strings between tags?

Comment: in file and yes I want to apply arbitrary upper/lower case modification

Comment: @UmeshChandraKahali: if any of these answers solved your problem, please Accept one of them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New answer to match the updated question (sample input and desired output changed since the original question).  Updated again on Mar 9, 2014, per the op's request to always uppercase the first word in a title tag.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# Add your articles and prepositions here!!!
my @lowercase = qw(a an at for in is the to);

# Use a hash since lookup is easier later.
my %lowercase;
# Populate the hash with keys and values from @lowercase.
# Values could have been anything, but it needs to match the number of keys, so this is easiest.
@lowercase{@lowercase} = @lowercase;

open(F, "foo.txt") or die $!;
while(<F>) {
  if (m/^<title/i) {
    chomp;
    my @words;
    my $line = $_;
    # Save the opening <title> tags
    my $titleTag = $line;
    $titleTag =~ s/^(<[^>]*>).*/$1/;
    # Remove any tags in <brackets>
    $line =~ s/<[^>]*>//g;
    # Uppercase the first letter in every word, except for those in a certain list.
    my $first = 1;
    foreach my $word (split(/\s/, $line)) {
      if ($first) {
        $first = 0;
        push(@words, ucfirst($word));
        next;
      }
      if ($first || exists $lowercase{$word}) { push(@words, "$word") }
      else { push(@words, ucfirst($word)) }
    }
    print $titleTag . join(" ", @words) . "</title>\n";
  }
  else {
    print $_;
  }
}
close(F)
```

This code does make 2 assumptions:

1. Each `<title>...</title>` is on a single line.  It never wraps to more
   than one line in the file.
2. The opening `<title>` tag is at the beginning of the line.  This can be easily be changed in the code if desired though.

Comment: Sorry, had a slight regex mistake.  The code above has been corrected.

Comment: dear sir I have add some more conditions, please I need these to be sorted out sir. Thanks and please add this conditions also.

Comment: Could you clarify what conditions changed?  I can only see the new Question/conditions, so I don't know what's changed that this code can't handle.

Comment: condition is if a word that is in $lowercase (suppose is) and it is the first word of the <title> and is in lower case then it should be upper case.

Comment: OK, code updated to reflect the new requirement.  Please accept this answer to close out this question, and open a new question if you continue to need help.  Questions shouldn't be revised this much.

Answer (score 2):

Probably something like this then:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $lines = qq#
<title>The human nervous system</title>
<title>Terms for anatomical directions in the nervous system</title>
<title>Anatomical terms referring to directions</title>
#;

foreach my $line ( split(/\n/, $lines ) ) {

    $line =~ s|</?title>||g;

    if ( $line = /\w+/ ) {                # Skip if blank
        print "<title>" . ucfirst(
           join(" ",
               map{ !/^(in|the|on|or|to|for)$/i ? ucfirst($_) : lc($_); }
               split(/\s/, $line )
           )
        ) ."<\/title>\n";

    }
}
```

Or however you want to loop your file. But you are going to have to filter the terms you don't want converted like this. As I have shown.

Comment: dear sir though this is works fine but removes the tags. I like the tags to retain as is and the action will be only on <title> tags.

Comment: @UmeshChandraKahali The tags are only removed while altering the elements. See the **print** statement at start and end. So they **are** put back. Running the script sample as is will show the output.

Comment: @UmeshChandraKahali So I thin you wrote on and probably accepted the wrong answer.